# VS2010 MV3 - How can I share files between solutions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am the only developer for an application. All the files for this application are stored on the same computer and I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

The application has three solutions and these share common items such as some stylesheets, some javascript and shared views.

It's starting to become difficult when I change one file as I have to copy this to the other projects in the other solutions.

Is there a simple way that I could share files. Something that would help me be more productive. Possibly even some single user source code or a way of linking files between solutions.

Hope I can find someone to help me make my life easier.

Robert W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you work on your own I would suggest some kind of Source Control System. Team Server is now free with Visual Studio or you can use open source tools. Like this you can link to source files in other projects and you can reuse your files.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Use Source Control**! SVN is free so is TFS with Ultimate.
2. If its web based files (javscript, pictures, css, etc) use a virtual directory to point to the common code directories.
3. if its compiled code (C#,VB, etc) you can link the files. When adding an existing file in the dialog it will have a open button, with an arrow down. click the arrow down and "add as link" will be available. It will then use relative referencing to the other file. I use this technique for a SolutionAssemblyInfo.cs file.
   I would recommend placing the common files in the same directory as the solution file or no more than 1 folder deep.

Comment: Is it difficult to set up TFS and to edit and put back files. There just seems so much to learn I can hardly keep up :-(

Comment: Keep in mind that source code might seem like an extra hurdle. But it will save you when you go down a rabit hole and want to roll back. 
And you'll want to know what has changed on a file months later.
#2 & 3 are viable if you're not using source control